# Filter results from API with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am receiving data with API in Angular and trying to filter the result for the hotels with the min_price less than for example 50$!

```
$http.get($rootScope.baseurl + 'api/hotels/', {
        params: {
            page_size: $scope.page_size,
            page: $scope.page,
            goingTo: goingTo,
            ordering: $scope.sortBy,
            star: $scope.filter.star,
            min_price: ????
        }}).then(
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Hotels = data.data.results;
            $scope.count = data.data.count;
            $scope.loading = false;
            PageService.setContentReady();
        },
        function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            PageService.contentStatus = 'ready';
        }
    );
```

How to show hotels under 50$ ?

Comment: can you share sample response.

Comment: Please share the response JSON

Comment: We have "min_price": 50 (for example) for Hotel in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below your updated code

```
$http.get($rootScope.baseurl + 'api/hotels/', {
    params: {
        page_size: $scope.page_size,
        page: $scope.page,
        goingTo: goingTo,
        ordering: $scope.sortBy,
        star: $scope.filter.star,
        min_price: 50
    }
}).then(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.Hotels = data.data.results;
        $scope.Hotels = $scope.Hotels.filter(function(hotel){ return hotel.min_price < 50}); //filter hotels
        $scope.count = data.data.count;
        $scope.loading = false;
        PageService.setContentReady();
    },
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.loading = false;
        PageService.contentStatus = 'ready';
    }
);
```

Comment: Awesome, It is working (But without this line: min_price: 50)

Comment: Do have any idea how can make it dynamic and changing the min_price value with select option by user?

Comment: @Mohammad.Gh Just add the ng-model value of the select ?

Comment: And how can filtering min_price between two price?  50 < min_price< 80

Comment: @Mohammad.Gh `hotel > min_price && hotel < max_price`

Comment: Awesome, Thank you a lot, Can you help me more how to make min and max price dynamic by select option!?

Comment: @Mohammad.Gh I am glad to help you but you should try to find yourself. We are not code generator. This is a really simple question and you can easily find a solution yourself or on SO. Good luck in your research!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this onto the end of your statement:

```
// Assuming you're doing some kind of promise resolution;
let deferred = $q.defer();

.success((data) => {
  deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

The resulting data from this you can then filter:

```
// assume 'data' is your real resolved data;
let filteredData = data.filter((hotel) => hotel.min_price < 50);
```

That's ES6 syntax but you get the gist.